# How to use localstorage store the jquery mobile's checkbox state?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile, local-storage

```
<table data-role="table" data-mode="columntoggle" class="ui-responsive ui-shadow" data-column-btn-text="">
      <thead>
            <tr>
                <th data-priority="1" id="th0">1</th>
                <th data-priority="1" id="th1">2</th>
                <th data-priority="1" id="th2">3</th>
                <th data-priority="1" id="th3">4</th>
                <th data-priority="1" id="th4">5</th>
           </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
           <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>4</td>
                <td>5</td>
          </tr>
    </tbody>    
</table>
```

I did a table use jquery mobile.okay!and then i wanna hide some columns,so i tapping the "Columns..." , now i hidden the columns,but how i use the localstorage store my operation,when i refresh this page it's not all columns show. i know there got 'ui-checkbox-on' and 'ui-checkbox-off'....
THX!

Answer (score 1):

To store data:

```
localStorage.setItem("username", username);
```

To retrieve data:

```
var username = localStorage.getItem("username");
```

In your case something like:

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="toggle('.myClass', this)" >
<div class="myClass">
   check 1.
</div>

<input type="checkbox"  onclick="toggle('.myClass2', this)" >
<div class="myClass2">
   check 2.
</div>

<input type="checkbox"  onclick="toggle('.myClass3', this)" >
<div class="myClass3">
   Check 3.
</div>
```

JS:

```
function toggle(className, obj) {
    var $input = $(obj);
    if ($input.prop('checked')) {
        $(className).css("visibility", "hidden");
        console.log(className);
        localStorage.setItem(className,'hidden')
    } 
    else {
        $(className).css("visibility", "visible");
        localStorage.setItem(className,'visible')
    }
}
```

CSS:

```
input[type="checkbox"] {
  clear: both;
  float:left;  
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dudu84/jxghvoqv/2/

Comment: THx dude! but my question is storage the checkbox state

Comment: Sorry. I've update the answer with a fiddle. See if it helps: https://jsfiddle.net/dudu84/jxghvoqv/1/